Chromedriver diables use of Trusted Platform (TPM)
When I use Chromedriver the Trusted Platform (TPM) is diabled in an application. When I do the same with in a regular Chrome session on the same system the use TPM works fine. How can use TPM during a Chromedriver session?
I have looked for a startup option for the Chromedriver to solve this. Nothing found. Furthermore I tried to find an option in the Chrome settings without any result.
